# PHP fails on simple if statement

Tags: php

Here is my code

```
<?php

$type="gt";

if($type=="os");
{
  echo "1";
}

if($type=="gt");
{
  echo "2";
}

?>
```

It gives me 12 as result. Both if's executes! Any idea??

P.S: I'm running code on xampp.

Comment: See that semicolon: `if($type=="gt");`? You can think of it as: `if($type=="gt"){Do nothing}`

Comment: you can simply write : echo ($type == "gt") ? 2 : 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
<?php

  $type="gt";

  if($type=="os")
  {
       echo "1";
  }

  if($type=="gt")
  {
      echo "2";
  }

?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Semicolon and re-run the code . Semicolon means it is treated as a statement , as each statement in PHP is terminated by a ; so each line will be executed .

```
<?php

  $type="gt";

  if($type=="os")
  {
       echo "1";
  }

  if($type=="gt")
  {
      echo "2";
  }

?>
```